# What is the Likelihood of a car alternator fault being due to worn field winding brushes?

Tags: alternator, charging

TL;DR: If a 2001 Toyota Corolla alternator is faulty, how likely it is that the field winding brushes have gone open circuit?
It's reasonably likely that the alternator is the original one.

**___________________**

My son's 2001 Toyota Corolla has stopped charging its battery.
The battery can be charged using an external charger and it holds charge.
The alternator does not draw substantial current when off.
Indications are that the alternator system is dead.

It seems likely that there has not been a diode short circuit as in my experience these draw substantial battery current.
A mechanic will remove and replace the alternator at an acceptable price.
Alternator replacement is acceptable if necessary.
I'm not inclined to do alternator diode replacements myself or other repairs
**but** if brush failure was the cause then a repair sounds liable to be a sensible solution.

Based on personal experience and the age of the vehicle,
**Can anyone suggest how likely it is that the field winding brushes have gone open circuit?**

---

Added: I was/am looking for a probabalistic estimate based on experience or knowledge. I've seen it happen once that I was aware of and have known of a number of diode failures. So, for my small sample I find the brush failure % low. I'd expect that there are people who see enough of these to be able to make a better estimate.

Comment: The car's almost twenty years old, and the alternator brushes could certainly have failed. The brushes and regulator are replaceable as a unit, and may be replaceable without removing the alternator from the vehicle. That'd be easer (and less expensive) than replacing the whole alternator. I'm not usually a fan of throwing parts at a problem, but brush replacement is appealing in this case.

Comment: " how likely it is that the field winding brushes have gone open circuit" As likely as any other component in the alternator failing to do its job.

Comment: @Moab I was/am looking for a probabalistic estimate based on experience or knowledge. I've seen it happen once that I was aware of and have known of a number of diode failures. SO for my small sample I find the brush failure % low. I'd expect that there are peopl;e who see enough of these to be able to make a better estimate.

Comment: I use to rebuild them, saw every type of failure. Not familiar with that model, sorry

Comment: At nearly 20 years I would pull the belt and spin the alternator to hear what the bearings sound like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen bad brushes on an alternator ; they have been very trouble free compared to generators where I replaced brushes many times. I had one car that destroyed alternators, it was always the diodes ( the alternator was located in a very hot location  near the exhaust manifold .)

Comment: Well, one style of brushes was end on to the rotor with one brush on the centreline, used to "drill" through the copper slipring and cause issues... but depends on what you work on I suppose...

Comment: Thanks. That's the sort of statistical response I was after. I'll leave it a while longer but so far this comes closest to "I've seen N alternator failures and Y of them were brushes" type answer. that I sought.

Answer (score 2):

Many alternators had/have brushes and if you can get replacement brushes it is an easy fix.

I used to keep several brush sets for alternators as faults were “obvious” depending on the behavior of the warning light on the dash: dimly glowing or flickering or fully on.

Comment: Aha, remember the good ole days when you could drive down to the local alternator repair shop and pick up a pair of brushes for a few bucks. Those days are gone, sigh.